# What are the color codes for infinity switches on a Frigidaire range?

Tags: wiring, range

I have Frigidaire Electric Coil Drop-in Range (FED300ESB) and I am replacing one of the small infinity switches. I cannot find a color coded wiring gride for L1H1 etc. Does anyone know the colors for the infinity switches?

Comment: Appliances that I have opened often have a paper schematic inside them, perhaps in the control panel. Maybe there is one inside your stove?

Comment: I suspect that you should've gone with "infinity switch". I can't seem to figure out what an "affinity switch" might be.

Comment: These are definitely infinity switches. You sure there isn't a diagram in a pocket in the back of the unit? There's been one in every appliance I've ever opened, though admittedly that's not as many as a professional repair person.

Comment: Infinite switch? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_switch